# Как сделать однострочный цикл в массиве/векторе в Rust?

Tags: массивы, циклы, for, vector, rust

Перешёл с Python на Rust, а на прошлом языке для заполнения массива циклом писалась конструкция на подобие:

```
array = [i for i in range(100)]
```

Возможно ли сделать тоже самое в Rust и как?

Comment: `let a: Vec<_> = (1..100).collect();`

Comment: [Обработка последовательности элементов с помощью итераторов](https://doc.rust-lang.ru/book/ch13-02-iterators.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List comprehension в самом общем виде `[f(i) for i in range(100) if cond(i)]` - собрать в список результаты выполнения функции `f` к тем элементам последовательности, которые удовлетворяют предикату `cond`:

```
let v: Vec<_> = (0..100).filter(cond).map(f).collect();
```

Например, вектор квадратов всех нечётных чисел от 1 до 10:

```py
# python
[x*x for x in range(10) if x%2==1]
```

```rust
// Rust
let v: Vec<_> = (0..10).filter(|x| x % 2 == 1).map(|x| x * x).collect();
```